# How can I add a personalized symbol to Calendar entries?

Tags: ical

I would like to be able to record on my calendar a quick symbol to indicate that I exercised that day.  Is that possible?

Comment: Is it a stock symbol or a custom one that you created?  If it's just a regular symbol then it's only text and you should be able to enter it anywhere.

Comment: Like ⚽️⚾️⛳️⛷⛸⛹  ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to add symbols to iCal/Calendar.app:

1. Use **Emojis**. Emojis are Unicode characters and will be displayed without special software. Use Cmd + Ctrl + Space to insert emojis or any other special character.
2. Use the **find function**. Use a unique name for your event ("Exercise"), go to month view (Cmd + 3) and search for your event (Cmd + F)
3. Use a **separate calendar** to hide your other calendar temporarily. You will only see your exercise events.

You cannot add graphics to a events' title so it stands out easily. But I think using emojis as the first character for the title could work in your case.

Happy exercising!